# RIA Services with Windows Phone

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, wcf-ria-services

Is it possible to use RIA services with a silverlight windows phone application?  It seems like it may be not.. at least yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding WP7 support for RIA Services can be voted on here.

[RIA Services support for Windows Phone 7](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/57026-wcf-ria-services/suggestions/746044-ria-services-support-for-windows-phone-7?ref=comments)

It's not currently supported, however Nikhil did demonstrate WP7 working with his demo at Mix 10. Actually it didn't work in the demo, but the project runs if you download it.. he was just running out of time at the end and didn't notice the server wasn't running from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Because a RIA Service is a WCF service, you can connect to it.  However no, you don't get the generated classes and domain context like you do in Silverlight.  Hopefully Microsoft adds that support sometime in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a full blog post on this topic : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2010/12/03/how-to-open-a-wcf-ria-services-application-to-other-type-of-clients-the-soap-endpoint-3-5.aspx demonstrating how to consume the SOAP endpoint of WCF RIA Services from a Windows Phone 7 (or WPF) clients to do CRUD operations.

Regards,

David Rousset